# React Navigation: Can't click tabs because of Image behind tab bar

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, tabnavigator, react-native-tabnavigator

In my React Native project, I have a top tab navigator that I created with `createMaterialTopTabNavigator`. I have an Image behind the tab bar. The code looks like this:

```
const TabNavigatorOuter = createMaterialTopTabNavigator(
    {
        a: {screen: a},
        b: {screen: b},
        c: {screen: c},
        d: {screen: d},
    },
    {
        tabBarOptions: {
            style: {
                backgroundColor: 'transparent',
                borderTopWidth: 0,
                position: 'absolute',
                left: 0,
                right: 0,
                top: 0,
                zIndex: 10
            },
            tabStyle: {
                zIndex: 10
            },
            labelStyle: {
                zIndex: 10
            },
        }
    }
)

const TabNavigatorContent = createAppContainer(TabNavigatorOuter);

<View>
    <Image
        source={require('@images/top-0.3.png')}
        style={{zIndex: 1, height: 50, top: 0}}
    />
    <TabNavigatorContent/>
</View>
```

Here's what this looks like:

[image]

**The Problem:**

I can't press any of the buttons `a`, `b`, `c`, or `d`. When I change the `zIndex` on the `Image` to 0 then I can click them, but I need it to be 1 in order for some of the other content to flow behind it. Even though I've set `zIndex` on the elements of `tabBarOptions` to 10, I still can't click them. I assume there's some wrapper in the tab navigator that I can't access that has `zIndex` of 0.

Does anyone know how I can approach this?

Comment: Add z-index to TabNavigatorComponent :)

Comment: i think you should give negitive zIndex style like this  tabBarOptions: { style:{zIndex:-10}}

Answer (score 0):

Have you given this a shot? The order of the components matters, although I am not sure if it will solve your problem in this case

```
<View>
    <TabNavigatorContent/>
    <Image
        source={require('@images/top-0.3.png')}
        style={{zIndex: 1, height: 50, top: 0}}
    />
</View>
```